# Dynamic class loading in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am not sure if this is possible or not, but my requirement is to load colors from a class say 'A' but internally it will refer/create an object for B or C where actual methods are define. depends on some condition A will create refer /object for B or C only once. if i call a method on A then i need to get from B or C without checking condition again. assuming both B and C are having same method signatures.

Is this possible? if so how can we achieve this. PS : using swift.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)

```
protocol myCustomProtocol {
    func myCallBackFunction();
}

class A : myCustomProtocol{

    func myCallBackFunction(){
        println("I AM A")
    }
}

class B : myCustomProtocol{

    func myCallBackFunction(){
        println("I AM B")
    }
}

class C{

    func doSomethingWithMyCustomProtocol(mcp : myCustomProtocol){
        mcp.myCallBackFunction();
    }
}

var myA = A();
var myB = B();
var myC = C();

myC.doSomethingWithMyCustomProtocol(myA);
myC.doSomethingWithMyCustomProtocol(myB);

//output: 
//I AM A
//I AM B
```

Comment: we need to check every time wether we need to pass myA or myB? can we avoid this?